# Linq query - use string as property?

Tags: c#, linq

Code:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(SomeObject).GetProperties())
                {
                    if (Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(SomeCustomAttribute)))
                    {
                        column.Expression(p => p.Name);
                    }
                }
```

I want to add columns which have SomeCustomAttribute data-annotation assigned.

How to use prop.Name (name of the property) as an property instead of manual p.Name?

For example..

```
...
column.Expression(p => prop.Name);
...
```

column.Expression is

```
ITableColumn Expression<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```

Comment: You want to get the value of the property? so if prop.Name == "Foo", you want p.Foo?

Comment: Yes, exactly. How to do that?

Comment: Dynamic LINQ!!! http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: @Xatep, please post `column.Expression` definition.

Comment: @Dennis ITableColumn Expression<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have this types defined:

```
interface ITableColumn { }
class SomeObject 
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
class Column<TModel>
{
    public ITableColumn Expression<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        // just a stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

To invoke `Column.Expression` for single property, obtained via reflection, you have to build member expression first:

```
    private static LambdaExpression MakeMemberExpression(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var instanceExpression = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        return Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(instanceExpression, propertyInfo), instanceExpression);
    }
```

As long as you don't know `TProperty` statically, you don't need to build strongly typed lambda (`Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`).
Now, let's invoke it:

```
        var property = typeof(SomeObject)
            .GetProperty("MyProperty");

        var columnType = typeof(Column<>)
            .MakeGenericType(typeof(SomeObject));

        var expressionMethod = columnType
            .GetMethod("Expression")
            .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);

        var expr = MakeMemberExpression(property);

        expressionMethod.Invoke(new Column<SomeObject>(), new[] { expr });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been trying to get this to work the whole day. Thanks! :)